# zoom body with keeping aspect ratio correctly

Tags: jquery, css, zooming, aspect-ratio

I have this single page application for web that has a fixed width and height. I need to fit to the page all times. I'm having issues scaling it.

If I only scale it based on it's with it works perfectly fine.

```js
var app = $('body');
var appWidth = app.width();
var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
var ratio = currentWidth / appWidth;

app.css('zoom', ratio);

$(window).resize(function() {
  currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
  ratio = currentWidth / appWidth;
  app.css('zoom', ratio);
  console.log(ratio);
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: red;
}
body {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 960px;
  height: 540px;
  position:relative;
}
p{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <h1>This content shrinks once it's scaled</h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
  <p>This shouldn't get cut off once it's scaled</p>
</body>
```

However I'm trying to achieve scale both from it's height and width without stretching to fit it correctly on the page. I'm aware there might be some extra spacing in same cases but that's fine as long as it's not stretched.

Below code is the far as I got. As you can see it doesn't scale well once it's scaled from both sides it's getting confused.

```js
var app = $('body');
var appWidth = app.width();
var appHeight = app.height();
var lastWidth = window.innerWidth;
var lastHeight = window.innerHeight;
var currentWidth;
var currentHeight;
var ratio;


app.css('zoom', ratio);

fitToPage();

$(window).resize(function() {
  fitToPage();
});


function fitToPage() {
  currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
  currentHeight = window.innerHeight;

  if(currentWidth !== lastWidth && currentHeight !== lastHeight){
    console.log('both width and height changed');
    ratio = currentWidth / appWidth;
    app.css('zoom', ratio);
    lastWidth = window.innerWidth;
    lastHeight = window.innerHeight;
  }
  else if (currentWidth !== lastWidth){
    console.log('width changed');
    ratio = currentWidth / appWidth;
    app.css('zoom', ratio);
    lastWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }
  else if (currentHeight !== lastHeight){
    console.log('height changed');
    ratio = currentHeight / appHeight;
    app.css('zoom', ratio);
    lastHeight = window.innerHeight;
  }
   
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: red;

}
body {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 960px;
  height: 540px;
  position:relative;
}
p{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <h1>This content shrinks once it's scaled</h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
  <p>This shouldn't get cut off once it's scaled</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm having a look. First of all it seems to never get into your last else-if-statement.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I have modified the code. I revert it back it should work now if you open again.
https://output.jsbin.com/sejabi/

Comment: Is that the behavior you look for : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/VmMPGd/ ?

Answer (score 0):

not too sure, but if you only look at window's width and keep a body with same height/width ratio. CSS can help :

*(height can overflow html)*

```css
html {
  background-color: red;
  position:relative;
  padding-top:56.25%;/* 54/96=0.5625 */
}
body {
  background-color: gray;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test App</h1>
```

to understand how this works see:

> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties
>
> **`<percentage>`**
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and 'padding-bottom'. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

You can also  avoid the box to be taller than window's height:

*(box will not overflow the window)*

```css
html {
  background:tomato;
  margin:0;
  max-width:156vh;
  position:relative;
  margin: 5vh auto;
}
html:before {
  content:'';
  padding-top:56.25%;
  display:inline-block
}
body {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:#aaa;
  /* makeup*/
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  color:white;
  font-size:10vh;
}
```

```html
keep my ratio & inside window
```

Comment: This looks like a nice css solution but the content inside the css doesn't scale on size change.

Comment: @TanKucukhas okay, but there will be a point where content inside will be too small to be seen or read or too big to be comfortable to see :) example with test and image resized according to ratio http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VmMPGd

Comment: In my case I'm working in fixed widths, heights and absolute positions, I know it would be easier if the width was dynamic.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make the app take most space on any kind of device. Lets say you are running the app on 1920x1080 that is going to perfectly fit on full screen because aspect ratio matches, however if you have a different aspect ratio like 800 640 there is going to be space but still the app will take the most space it can.

Using browser zoom helps keeping the layout separate without touching the layout width.

Answer (score 0):

If you go over the width of 960px none of your if-else-conditions hold, so the scaling stops.

You can copy this to see it in your console. I added a case for going over 960px width.

```
function fitToPage() {
  console.log("ratio" +ratio);
  console.log("appwidth " +appWidth);
  console.log("curwidth " +currentWidth);
  console.log("curheight " +currentHeight);
  console.log("appheight " +appHeight);
  currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
  currentHeight = window.innerHeight;

  if (appWidth > currentWidth && appHeight > currentHeight) {
      console.log('both');
      ratio = currentWidth / appWidth;
      app.css('zoom', ratio);
  } else if (appWidth > currentWidth) {
      console.log('only width');
      ratio = currentWidth / appWidth;
      app.css('zoom', ratio);
  } else if (appHeight > currentHeight) {
      console.log('only height');
      ratio = currentHeight / appHeight;
      app.css('zoom', ratio);
  }else if (appWidth < currentWidth){
      ratio = currentWidth / appWidth;
      app.css('zoom', ratio);
      console.log('smallercase');
  }

}
```

Comment: Improved the code little but now it scales initially and detects if it's width scaled, height scaled or both but still in same cases it does not fit on the page.